# Custom Control dependency property changed not firing when updating datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a sample program to recreate the issue I am having.

Control:

```
public class PropertyUpdateControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(PropertyUpdateControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, ValueProperty_Changed));

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ValueProperty_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lPropertyUpdateControl = (PropertyUpdateControl) d;
        lPropertyUpdateControl.Value_Changed((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void Value_Changed(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        this.Value = newValue;
        this.Label = newValue.ToString();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Label), typeof(string), typeof(PropertyUpdateControl), new PropertyMetadata("Label"));

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Main Window

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private PropertyUpdateViewModel mPropertyUpdateViewModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.PropertyUpdateViewModel = new PropertyUpdateViewModel();
        this.ChangeCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ChangeImplementation);
    }

    public ICommand ChangeCommand { get; set; }

    public void ChangeImplementation()
    {
        if (this.PropertyUpdateViewModel == null)
        {
            this.PropertyUpdateViewModel = new PropertyUpdateViewModel();
        }
        else
        {
            this.PropertyUpdateViewModel = null;
        }
    }

    public PropertyUpdateViewModel PropertyUpdateViewModel
    {
        get { return this.mPropertyUpdateViewModel;}
        set { this.Set(ref this.mPropertyUpdateViewModel, value); }
    }
}

public class PropertyUpdateViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double mValue;

    private static int sInstanceCounter = 0;

    public PropertyUpdateViewModel()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref sInstanceCounter);
        this.Value = sInstanceCounter;
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return this.mValue; }
        set { this.Set(ref this.mValue, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mKeyMainWindowViewModel" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PropertyUpdateControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PropertyUpdateControl}">
                    <TextBlock 
                        Margin="25" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"></TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="mDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:PropertyUpdateViewModel}">
        <local:PropertyUpdateControl
            Value="{Binding Value}"></local:PropertyUpdateControl>

    </DataTemplate>


</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="mKeyMainWindowViewModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PropertyUpdateViewModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mDataTemplate}"/>
        <Button Content="Update Value" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

So basically the control seems to only be updated once. The label will always read 1 even after setting the view model to null and then to a new instance of the PropertyUpdateViewModel which will have an incrementing value. Why is the PropertyUpdateControl Value_Changed only called once and never called again even after the datacontext changes?

Comment: As a note, setting `this.Value = newValue` in a PropertyChangedCallback of the Value property is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue to be in

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(PropertyUpdateControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, ValueProperty_Changed));
```

It needs to be `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`.

This post has more info on binding for anyone interested https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm